# Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, disk-space

I want to know how can I claim my free space to the container disk0s2

```
#:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *121.3 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI ⁨EFI⁩                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
                    (free space)                         60.6 GB    -
   2:                 Apple_APFS ⁨Container disk1⁩         60.6 GB    disk0s2

/dev/disk1 (synthesized):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      APFS Container Scheme -                      +60.6 GB    disk1
                                 Physical Store disk0s2
   1:                APFS Volume ⁨Ace⁩                     15.4 GB    disk1s1
   2:              APFS Snapshot ⁨com.apple.os.update-...⁩ 15.4 GB    disk1s1s1
   3:                APFS Volume ⁨Preboot⁩                 268.1 MB   disk1s2
   4:                APFS Volume ⁨Recovery⁩                1.1 GB     disk1s3
   5:                APFS Volume ⁨Ace - Data⁩              4.7 GB     disk1s4
   6:                APFS Volume ⁨VM⁩                      1.1 MB     disk1s6
```

When I run the command `diskutil apfs resizecontainer disk0s2 0`

I'm facing this error ->

```
Error: -69743: The new size must be different than the existing size
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please paste the text from command outputs rather than posting screen shots of text - images are not text searchable, nor text copiable.  Also, format the text using code formatting.

Comment: You've chosen to rollback the change to the title of the question. That's entirely up to you, but note that it was done in order to widen the possibility of other people fully understanding the question at first glance, and thus increasing engagement. Otherwise the question title is quite cryptic unless time is taken to read all of the text. It will also help future questioners to find your question and its answers rather than take the time to write their own. Please consider reverting the title back to the amendment.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you will not be able to. The GPT shows a block of 60.6 GB of free space before the `disk0s2` partition. When you are asking `diskutil` to resize the `disk0s2` container to the end of available free space, its end is already at the end of the free space, so cannot fulfil your request. A partition cannot be extended backwards either from the front (as it were). At the partition table level everything has physical boundaries. It's only when a partition is labelled as an APFS container do things get more dynamic with its contents.

It looks like the disk was previously split into other partitions, the first of which has subsequently been erased.

I would suggest a solid backup and a reinstall, making full use of all the space. It's been a long time since I have done any recovery work in macOS, especially with APFS, so you may need to remove the existing partitioning scheme beforehand in recovery mode. Perhaps another contributor with more experience can offer some guidance.

In addition, please update your original question with details of what hardware and OS version you are on. To me it looks like an Intel Mac. This will be useful for other contributors.

Answer (score 0):

Easy would be make a backup and erase install. Next hard would be to make a new APFS container from the free space.

Then install macOS on the “free space” and choose to migrate all data from the disk0s2 system.

Once you’re sure migration is good, delete disk0s2 and grow the “free space” container to use all space.

You can’t grow a partition to space that exists before it but you can grow if the free space is listed after the container disk.

The error you face means there’s no free space after disk1 container.